# what is the Best tool for automation Test .Net "Windows Services"?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

Guys could any suggest the best tool to automate unit testing especially for the "Windows services"?

Answer (score 3):

It's best that the services themselves are humble classes that delegate to the buisness logic classes.  These can then be tested using NUnit etc.

Comment: Yes, we use the TopShelf project for service hosting. This keeps our logic seperated from the IServiceBase implementation

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2010 would be my choice.

You are going to have to write code to test the service and the usual ways to do this is to either write a test harness that exercises all the functionality or to pull the guts of the service code into unit tests. In either case you need VS. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10153/Debugging-Windows-Services-under-Visual-Studio-NET) might be helpful.